# How to use the "Or" statement when having multiple conditions in the Where clause in SQLite?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am trying to retrieve data that has "Positive" result and the code set that contains any of these codes: [U071, R12, Z515, R509] as my desired goal for Table 1. I have tried using "or" but it kept giving me a mixture of negative and positive results instead of positive results only. I hope my question is clear as I am fairly new here.

Desired goal for Table 1:

| ID | START_DATE | TEST RESULT | Code | END_DATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 03-31-2021 | positive | U071 | 03-31-2021 |
| 2 | 06-06-2020 | positive | R12 | 06-09-2020 |
| 2 | 06-06-2020 | positive | Z515 | 06-10-2020 |
| 3 | 06-30-2021 | positive | R509 | 07-02-2021 |
| 4 | 08-08-2020 | positive | U071 | 08-10-2020 |
| 4 | 08-09-2020 | positive | Z515 | 08-10-2020 |

Note: I would also like ID 2 to be grouped as 1.

The problem:

| ID | START_DATE | TEST RESULT | Code | END_DATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 03-31-2021 | positive | U071 | 03-31-2021 |
| 2 | 06-05-2020 | negative | R12 | 06-09-2020 |
| 2 | 06-05-2020 | negative | Z515 | 06-09-2020 |
| 3 | 06-03-2021 | positive | R509 | 07-02-2021 |
| 4 | 08-10-2020 | negative | U071 | 08-10-2020 |
| 4 | 08-06-2020 | positive | Z515 | 08-10-2020 |

My code:

```
CREATE TABLE table1 AS
select   ID
        ,TEST_RESULT  
        ,START_DATE
        ,END_DATE
        ,Code
from table0
where TEST_RESULT = 'POSITIVE' AND Code = 'U071' OR Code = 'Z20828' OR DIAGNOSIS_CD = 'Z20822' OR DIAGNOSIS_CD = 'R112' OR DIAGNOSIS_CD = 'R509'
group by ID, START_DATE
ORDER BY ID;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the real issue is you did not use ( after the and.  But you can use IN to make it clearer -- like this:

```
where TEST_RESULT = 'POSITIVE' AND (Code IN ('U071','Z20828') OR DIAGNOSIS_CD IN ('Z20822','R112','R509'))
```